# block eslint and prettier from reformatting closing brackets on HTML elements

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, eslint, prettier

OK this is driving me nuts! How can i stop eslint/prettier from moving the closing brackets in a DIV element down to a new line on save? I have tried almost all the eslint rules and turning prettier on and off.
I have attached a screenshot to show the community what i mean. Since it's a code formatting issue stackoverflow wants me to format correctly (which defeats the purpose).
Much help is appreciated!  thank you.

[html_code_all_wonky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUCUB.png)

Comment: Hehe, I think if you want to use Prettier you have to embrace the wonkiness. It does that to keep line length down. It personally took some getting used to, but I find it more readable now.

Answer (score 2):

On prettier config file (.prettierrc.js is my preference), add

```
jsxBracketSameLine: false
```

More info here
https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#jsx-brackets

Answer (score 1):

ESLint rule is in `eslint-plugin-react` package: [jsx-closing-bracket-location](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-closing-bracket-location.md#validate-closing-bracket-location-in-jsx-reactjsx-closing-bracket-location):

```
// for example, jsx-closing-bracket-location: [1, 'after-props']

<Hello
  firstName="John"
  lastName="Smith" />
```

---

Prettier does not provide a way to configure this. By design. So, you have to turn it off in-place:

```
<div className="App">
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  {/* prettier-ignore */}
  <h2>
    Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
</div>

<div className="App">
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  {/* prettier-ignore */}
  <Hello
    lastName="Smith"
    firstName="John" />
</div>
```

Comment: @NeverSummer70 cool! If it's a working solution for you consider accepting an answer

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding this rule to eslint:

```json
rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { bracketSameLine: false }]
}
```